# Jess Editor Plugin not Appearing in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, plugins, editor, jess, eclipse-luna

I have the Jess DE installed on an old version of Eclipse (Helios), and when I open any of my Jess files there, they are nicely displayed with appropriate colors, etc. I installed a newer version of Eclipse (Luna) in order to install PyDev, and meanwhile added all the Jess editor plugin files. I added them in exactly the corresponding subfolders as my older version of Eclipse, but have had no luck getting those files to open with the right editor. They'll open, but only as plain text, and trying to do an open with does not show the Jess Editor as an option. I restarted Eclipse a couple of times, but no luck. I also tried to follow these instructions:
"Help > Software Updates > Manage Configuration in Eclipse, and enable the JessDE feature"

but that menu doesn't actually seem to appear in Luna. Installation details under the plugins tab also doesn't seem to show the Jess editor.

Any ideas what could be going wrong here? I'd love to have just a single version of Eclipse running on my machine, instead of several...

Thanks!

Comment: Start Eclipse specifying the -clean option to get it to rebuild the plugins cache.

Answer (score 1):

I have your same problem. In mine Eclipse KEPLER version goes all right, but when I do the SAME installation in LUNA, something goes wrong.

Probably, the last version of JESS (7.1p2) doesn't is compatible with LUNA. I hope not.